# CSS animation speed regular expressions (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I need regular expressions that would extract time elements from CSS:

e.g. 4000ms or 4s

All I've got is this: `preg_match_all('/([0-9]{1-10}(ms|s)/i', $css, $timeValues);`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: found my own mistake. Got a better result, but still it adds "ms" and "s" to results:

preg_match_all('/([0-9]{1,10}(ms|s))/i', $css, $timeValues);

result: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4000ms
            [1] => 4s
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4000ms
            [1] => 4s
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ms
            [1] => s
        )

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incorrectly using the range quantifier `{min, max}`, and missing a closing parenthesis.

You can modify the regular expression as follows:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]{1,10})m?s/i', $css, $timeValues);
print_r($timeValues[1]);
```

Comment: For the overall matches, just use `$timeValues[0]`

Comment: good one, thanks. But it still returns additional 

 [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4000
            [1] => 4000
        )

should it be like that?

Comment: -webkit-animation-name: cssload-spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: cssload-spin;
  animation-duration: 4000ms;

Comment: Works fine? For overall matches - https://eval.in/390574, for just the numbers - https://eval.in/390575

Comment: Hi! yes. Works perfectly fine. I improved it a little bit so that it allows decimal points ( like 1.2s ):

/([0-9]+[\.0-9]*)m?s/i